# Shell Method About Y-Axis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

In my calculus course, we just covered the Shell Method and its uses. I have been doing the homework for a few hours and I am absolutely stumped by a question.

The question states:

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region in the first quadrant bounded by the graph of the equation about the given line.
>
> $$ x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 12^{2/3} $$
>
> (i) the $x$-axis; (ii) the $y$-axis

The question is multiple choice and lists the following possible answers:

1. (i) $\frac{13824\pi}{25}$; (ii) $\frac{13824\pi}{25}$
2. (i) $\frac{3456\pi}{25}$; (ii) $\frac{18432\pi}{35}$
3. (i) $\frac{4608\pi}{35}$; (ii) $\frac{18432\pi}{35}$
4. (i) $\frac{18432\pi}{35}$; (ii) $\frac{18432\pi}{35}$
5. (i) $\frac{18432\pi}{35}$; (ii) $\frac{4608\pi}{35}$

---

I quickly worked out the answer to the first part (the $x$-axis) and I ended up with $$\frac{18432\pi}{35}$$

This all seemed fine to me and it narrowed my options down to either choice 4 or 5.

However, once I started working on the second part (the $y$-axis) things got messy.

When I solved for $y$, I ended up with:

$$y = \sqrt{[12^{2/3} - x^{2/3}]^3}$$

This could of course be simplified further, but I had no problem with this equation. It seemed correct and I felt ready for the next step.

Because this is the Shell Method about the y-axis, I needed to find the information for a rectangle which ran parallel to $x = 0$. So I drew up a graph, added a rectangle, and began labeling it (for the sake of keeping track of things). Goal number 1: find $h(x)$. At any given value, the height of my parallel rectangle should be a point on the curve. So this led me to say:

$$h(x) = \sqrt{[12^{2/3} - x^{2/3}]^3}$$

Next I needed to identify $p(x)$. This was also fairly. Because I am using the y-axis as my axis of revolution $p(x)$ should just be:

$$p(x) = x$$

Now the shell method defines the equation for a vertical axis of revolution as:

$$ V = 2\pi \int_a^b p(x)h(x)dx $$

So filling everything in:

$$ V = 2\pi \int_0^{12} (x \sqrt{[12^{2/3} - x^{2/3}]^3})dx $$

The definite integral of this produced $\frac{9216\pi}{35}$. However, not only do I not have this option:

> (i) $\frac{18432\pi}{35}$; (ii) $\frac{9216\pi}{35}$

The question does not give any option which includes "$\frac{9216\pi}{35}$".

Can anybody help me identify what I did wrong and how I can fix it? I would be very grateful.

---

I have also included a screenshot of my work: (Please excuse my poor handwriting in the image. I have only recently begun using a tablet for working out problems.)
[image: 7.3 Shell Method Issue]

*In the image, "3/2" is used rather than the square root of the cube.*

Comment: Draw a picture. By symmetry they are the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Are you saying the volume should be the same for either axis? The domain is naturally limited to `-12 <= x <= 12`. If the domain was further restricted to `0 <= x <= 12`, then I would agree that these should be the same. However, when revolving around the X-axis, the domain is twice as large vs. revolving around the Y-axis which restricts the domain to only being above 0.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, but if I am revolving the Y-axis, should I still use numbers on the other side of the axis?

Comment: It is the frst quadrant part tht is being rotated, the problem is explicit. That is symmetric abou the line $y=x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, can you explain what you mean by: "That is symmetric about the line $y = x$"? I originally interpreted "revolving the region in the first quadrant" to mean "only the first quadrant revolves; so ignore everything below (0, 0)." However, using that meaning causes both answers to be ${9216\pi}/{35}$ which is not a valid option.

Comment: It means you can interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$. As to the actual computation of the integral, I have not done it. But the equality of the two volumes can be seen at a glance.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thank you so much for explaining that. I believe I now understand what you mean. I was viewing y as only being greater than 0, but I now see that y can be negative (because it is a square root). If you post the information you gave me as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I see a difficulty as well:  I just worked this by disk method about the $ \ x-$ axis and by shell method about the $ \ y-$ axis and get the same volume for both:  $ \frac{9216 \pi}{35} \ $  .  It looks to me like _none_ of the options are correct.  (I'm wondering whether the problem poser put a factor of 2 in the wrong place, then just used the fact that both answers should be the same by symmetry...) BTW, the shell method integral is horrible; the disk method is far easier to apply here (fewer terms and the numbers are nicer to deal with).

Comment: Note that $y$ cannot be negative, we are rotating a first quadrant region. One uses the same method (disk or shell, whichever is easier) for both questions, and one gets the same integral, with the dummy variable of integration changing, which makes no difference.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, I personally dislike the disk method and find shell to be more understandable, but too each their own. In this case, yes, disk might be easier to integrate with. On topic, technically the input for x can be between -12 and 12. In the image I included, you can see where I corrected my answer to account for this. However, because the question specifies "first quadrant region", this does pose a problem. The "first quad." restriction means $x \ge 0$. But I suppose I am just going to ignore this restriction because there are no compatible answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, why could $y$ not be negative? For any value of $x$, there should be a negative and a positive $y$. $y = \sqrt{ ... }$, thus $y$ can be both positive and negative. However, yes, there is the issue that the question says "first quad." I'm not sure what to do about that restriction. If I follow it, there are no valid answers. If I ignore it, then answer #4 should be correct.

Comment: The correct answer is $\frac{9216}{35}\pi$ for each.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, with or without the quadrant restriction? With the quadrant restriction, I agree. By the way, [here is a graph showing the negative side of the equation.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eus70blptp6)

Comment: Yes, with the quadrant restriction, it is right there explicitly  in the problem statement, no interpretation involved.  If we decide to ignore the quadrant restriction for some reason the volumes *are still equal*, each is just twice as big.

Comment: I suspect whoever posed the question wrote the choice for revolving half of the astroid (which would be two quadrants), then revised the question to the first quadrant only and forgot to change the volume.  (I've seen that happen on multiple-choice problems -- and have done it myself a couple of times...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner, possibly. The homework assignments are all created using [Blackboard Diploma](http://www.blackboard.com/Partnerships/Content-Distribution-Program/Blackboard-Diploma.aspx). I have frequently found that these tests are filled with errors like this. (Which is quite a pain to deal with when you are learning the subject.) But yes, I would guess the original author either forgot to revise the answers or forgot to revise the question.